# R - Selecting elements from factors

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, element

If I have a dataframe as follows

```
   a     b
1   5   red
2  11   red
3   7   red
4   1   red
5   3 green
6   8 green
7  12 green
8   6 green
9   2  blue
10  9  blue
11 10  blue
12  4  blue
```

How can I select a certain element from each factor?

For example, how would I able to select...

- the third element for each colour.
- the min value for each colour.

I would like to display the result as a dataframe, showing the result for each colour.

Like this

```
     result
red        1
green      3
blue       2
```

Here are my current attempts

- the min value for each colour.

  `a <- sample(1:12,12)
  b <- gl(3, 4, labels = c("red", "green", "blue"))
  df <- data.frame(a ,b) 
  result <- tapply(df$a, df$b, min)
  data.frame(result)`

This seems to work well and give me the result I'm after.

- the third element for each colour

  tapply(df$a, df$b, FUN = function(x) x[3])

Could solutions only use base-package please.

Comment: If you are after the 3rd element, `with(df1, tapply(a, b, FUN=function(x) x[3]))` instead of `x[1]`

Comment: Thanks, was typo. Edited above post.

Comment: Wrap it with `data.frame` to convert the vector to data.frame. ie. `data.frame(v1=with(df1, tapply(a, b, FUN='[', 3)))`

Comment: Did that answer the question you posted?

Comment: why not using `aggregate` which is base `R`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can group by 'b' column and get the `min` of 'a' within `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(b) %>%
    summarise(a= min(a)) #or
    #slice(which.min(a))
```

For getting the third value of 'a' for each 'b', use `slice`

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(b) %>%
    slice(3)
```

---

If we need only `base R` solutions, one way is `ave` to get the third element.  Grouped by 'b', we get the sequence, compare with 3 to get a logical index, and subset the original dataset.

```
df1[with(df1, ave(seq_along(a), b, FUN=seq_along)==3),]
```

Or with `tapply` without the anonymous function call

```
with(df1, tapply(a, b, FUN=`[`, 3))
```

NOTE: The `base R` solution for finding the `min` is already in the OP's post.

Comment: I want to find a solution using the base package please

Comment: @user3200293  Updated the post.  Please check.